# Can I use linkserver to SQL Server on SQL Server with the same instance?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I would like to know what is the best way for use linkserver.

I have a database in SQL Server called `Sales` and another database called `Menus`. Both are on the same instance of `JOSEPH-PC`.

My question: is it necessary to use linked server for it?

Or can I simply write a query like this:

```
select * 
from Sales.dbo.table1 a 
inner join Menus.dbo.accces b on a.code = b.code
```

How could I store data in 2 tables from different databases for example a master-detail from my app in C#?

Please let me know how I can make this.

Comment: you can't created link server having same instance, try using view.

Comment: @Ragul Actually you can :)

Comment: To author: best is to avoid dealing with two databases in single application - you can't have proper relations, you'll have user access problems, you'll have support problems, you need some nasty synchronization in case of backup restoration after failure etc etc. You have tables, you have schemas - enough granularity.

Comment: Yes you can do this without a linked server in the way you describe, but I don't think it is a good idea - think of your query performance

Answer (score 1):

i dont think you can create the linked server for same sql server instance. that has to be different instance or different server.

if its about the best way to access the different database in same server same instance?? the synonyms is here for that purpose.

create the synonyms for `access` from `Menus` in `sales` then you can use the `synonym` like local table on `sales` database.

in `sales` database run the following command to create the synonyms for **access** so now in **sales** you can use **menus_access** as table, which will refer the **access** inside the **menus** database

```
CREATE SYNONYM menus_access 
FOR Menus.dbo.access;
```

now in **sales** you can access the table as

```
 select * from menus_access
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create view on one of the two databases and make sure your connection string points to that database. You can create a view within SQL Server that connects to both databases like [Create view across multiple databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951320/create-view-across-multiple-databases)

You might also like to view [how to retrieve data from two different database using join in SQL Server 2005](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/446099/can-we-retrive-data-from-two-different-databases-a) the way you have tried to do it.